# Babel-Transpiler with Ruby on Rails: Getting Started

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, babeljs

I'm new to Rails but am familiar with JavaScript and ES6. I already have ES6 transpiling happening in my React-Rails gem so I can write normally in React, but any other js file I am limited to ES5.

I have to make a config file to tell it to get to work on ALL js files, but I am at a loss as to how to do that.

Any help, from a higher level explanation of what is going on to a more step by step approach, would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Rails uses a feature called the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to compile, concatenate and transform assets. Assets are generally style sheets, JavaScript files, and media files (mainly images).  The asset pipeline can perform different actions based on file type, which is the file extension of the filename.

The React-Rails gem integrates with the asset pipeline so that files ending in `.jsx` will go through Babel  preprocessing (by default).

Try putting your ES6 code into a file with a `.jsx` suffix, `app/assets/javascripts/myjavascript.jsx`. This should get them to run through Babel which will transform the ES6 code.

Comment: Thanks for the asset pipeline explanation, that gives me some perspective. The React-Rails gem is using Babel-Transpiler but I don't understand where to configure it (initializers?). I'd rather config the transpiler to work on my existing files than the other way around. Sorry for my lack of info, I'm just used to JS and using build tools like Webpack/Browserify/Gulp/Grunt to run these tasks explicitly.

Comment: Rails is all about convention over configuration. Asset pipeline convention runs off of file suffix. You can customize sprockets to tweak how this is handled, but may be more work than it's worth: check out https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md